# Putting a SwipeView inside a Fragment?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, user-experience, swipeview

**Problem:** Having a SwipeView inside a Fragment (So when the Fragment is active you can cycle through some other fargments)

**What I tried:** I tried implementing it the same way you would implement it normally but in the fragment:

**NORMAL WAY:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {



ViewPager viewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    SwipeAdapter swipeAdapter = new SwipeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(swipeAdapter);


}
```

}

**THE WAY I TRIED IT WITH A FRAGMENT:**

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {


ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.VIEWPAGER);
    SwipeAdapter swipeAdapter = new SwipeAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(swipeAdapter);
}
```

}

**THE ERROR:** It returns a "null object reference" when I try to set the adapter (I'm guessing it has problems with the FragmentManager)

**ADAPTER FOR BOTH EXAMPLES:**

```
public class SwipeAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public SwipeAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("count", position+1);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}
```

}

In the Main Activity I set up so you can switch fragments with buttons, and what I'm trying to implement in the second fragment is to be able to swipe through fragments with **SwipeView**

**MAIN ACTIVITY CODE:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button firstFragment, secondFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    firstFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstFragment);
    secondFragment = findViewById(R.id.secondFragment);

    firstFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadFragment(new FirstFragment());
        }
    });

    secondFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadFragment(new SecondFragment());
        }
    });
}

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but if anyone has a way to make this work any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the adapter because your view has not been created yet.

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
     savedInstanceState: Bundle?
 ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)


 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
     viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager) as ViewPager
     swipeAdapter = SwipeAdapter(childFragmentManager) 
     ...
 }
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but it's still giving me the same error :/ Maybe I just wrote it wrong?  I returned the inflated view in onCreateView, then in onViewCreated I attempted to set the adapter. (Also I'm not familiar with the syntax you wrote)

Comment: Can you update your code so I can see what you are doing now?

Comment: I updated it, I basically did what you said but in java

Comment: Yeah I just checked, although maybe this just isn't the way to do it. There is a dumb way to do it by setting the visibility to "View.GONE" and back to "View.VISIBLE"